# Trying to import lottie-web into my JS file shows many errors

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, lottie

I am making a custom audio player for my website using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.
I tried to make it work with Codepen but the animations weren't working, and on my text editor the animations also don't work but the following error appears:

Access to script at 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.teejay.trebedit/files/TrebEdit%20user%20files/My%20personal%20website/js/musicplayer.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-untrusted, https.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="audio-player-container">

  <audio src="http://www.geocities.ws/azohost/music/indexsong%20(1).wav" preload="metadata" loop></audio>

  <p class="audioP">Audio Player</p>

  <input class="play-ico" type="image" src="./img/btn_play.png">

  <span id="current-time" class="time">0:00</span>

  <input type="range" class="seek-slider" max="100" value="0">

  <span id="duration" class="time">0:00</span>  

  <output class="volume-output">100</output>

  <input type="range" class="volume-slider" max="100" value="100">

  <input class="sound-ico" type="image" src="./img/btn_sound.png">

</div>

<script type="module" src="./js/musicplayer.js"></script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to listen to some cool music.</noscript>
```

CSS:

```
/* Music player */

 /* Container for the audio player*/

 .audio-player-container {

 --seek-before-width:0%;

 --volume-before-width:100%;

 --buffered-width:0%;

 

 position:relative;

 

 margin:auto;

 width:95%;

 max-width:500px;

 height:100px;

 

 border:5px outset black;

 

 background:black;

 }

 

 .audio-player-container::before {

 position:absolute;

 content:"";

 

 width:calc(100% + 4px);

 height:calc(100% + 4px);

 

 left:-2px;

 top:-2px;

 }

 

 /* Text */

 .audioP {

 color: white;

 }

 

 .time {

 color: white;

 }

 

 /* Music length slider */

 .seek-slider {

 -webkit-appearance:none;

 appearance:none;

 

 height:5px;

 

 background:black;

 border:3px outset white;

 

 float:center;

 

 width:50%;

 

 -webkit-transition: .2s;

  transition: opacity .2s;

 }

 

 .seek-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {

 -webkit-appearance: none;

 appearance: none;

 

 width: 25px;

 height: 20px;

 border: 3px outset white;

 

 background:black;

 

 cursor:pointer;

 }

 

 .seek-slider::-moz-range-thumb {

 -webkit-appearance: none;

 appearance: none;

 

 width: 25px;

 height: 20px;

 border: 3px outset white;

  

 background:black;

  

 cursor: pointer;

 }

 

 /* Music volume slider*/

 .volume-slider {

 -webkit-appearance:none;

 appearance:none;

 

 height:5px;

 

 background:black;

 border: 3px outset white;

 

 float:center;

 

 width:50%;

 

 -webkit-transition: .2s;

 transition: opacity .2s;

 }

 

 .volume-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {

 -webkit-appearance: none;

 appearance: none;

 

 width: 25px;

 height: 20px;

 border: 3px outset white;

 

 background: black;

 

 cursor:pointer;

 }

 

 .volume-slider::-moz-range-thumb {

 -webkit-appearance: none;

 appearance: none;

 

 width: 25px;

 height: 20px;

 border: 0;

  

 background:black;

  

 cursor: pointer;

 }

 

 .play-ico {

 vertical-align:sub;

 }

 .sound-ico {

 vertical-align:sub;

 }

 

 output {

 display:inline-block;

 width:32px;

 color:white;

 

 text-align:center;

 

 margin:35px 2.5% 0 5%;

 float:left;

 clear:left;

 }
```

JavaScript:

```
//Objective: get the music player to work

// imports the Lottie library via Skypack

import lottieWeb from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/lottie-web';

//Assign variables

const playIconContainer = document.getElementById('../img/btn_play.png');

const audioPlayerContainer = document.getElementByClass('audio-player-container');

const seekSlider = document.getElementByClass('seek-slider');

const volumeSlider = document.getElementByClass('volume-slider');

const soundIconContainer = document.getElementById('../img/btn_sound.png');

let playState = 'play';

let soundState = 'unmute';

//Animation to change play button to pause button

const playAnimation = lottieWeb.loadAnimation({

  container: playIconContainer,

  path: '../img/btn_pause.png',

  renderer: 'svg',

  loop: false,

  autoplay: false,

  name: "Play Animation",

});

//Animation to change sound button to mute button

const soundAnimation = lottieWeb.loadAnimation({

  container: soundIconContainer,

  path: '../img/btn_mute.png'

  renderer: 'svg',

  loop: false,

  autoplay: false,

  name: "Sound Animation",

playAnimation.goToAndStop(14, true);

//Event to change the icon

playIconContainer.addEventListener('click',) () => {

  if(playState === 'play') {

    playAnimation.playSegments([14, 27], true);

  }

  else {

    playAnimation.playSegments([0, 14], true);

    playState = 'play';

  }

});

soundIconContainer.addEventListener('click',) () => {

  if(soundState === 'unmute') {

    soundAnimation.playSegments([0, 15], true);

  }

  else {

    soundAnimation.playSegments([15, 25], true);

    soundState = 'unmute';

  }

});

//Sliders animations

const showRangeProgress = (rangeInput) => {

  if(rangeInput === seekSlider){      audioPlayerContainer.style.setProperty('--seek-before-width', rangeInput.value / rangeInput.max * 100 + '%');

    } 

    else {

      audioPlayerContainer.style.setProperty('--volume-before-width', rangeInput.value / rangeInput.max * 100 + '%');

    }

}

seekSlider.addEventListener('input', (e) => {

    showRangeProgress(e.target);

});

volumeSlider.addEventListener('input', (e) => {

    showRangeProgress(e.target);

});
```

I got this code from the following website and tweaked it a bit to fit my tastes:
https://css-tricks.com/lets-create-a-custom-audio-player/

I have tried a few things. At first, the error displayed (with no "type='module'" in the html script tag) was: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
When i assigned the module type to the script shown above, the error shown at the beginning of this question appears.
Then i got a geocities.ws free domain, put my JavaScript file there and linked it to my html file, in hopes this would work. It unfortunately didn't change anything. A access control error appeared instead.
Here's the code:

```
<script type="module" src="http://www.geocities.ws/azohost/JS/musicplayer_20221103191020.js"></script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to listen to some cool music.</noscript>
```

I expected the code to be working, with the lottie-web library making my play and sound icons animate and change, and i also expected my sliders to work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: i added the script tag on the html section so you guys can see how I'm trying to import the JS file to the HTMl file, and i also added the other "solution" i tried that made the access control error appear.

Comment: The code you have provided seems okay. But I suppose the problem you are facing with the javascript import to your html file. I recommend provide The HTML code of that section. Also make sure to navigate to the js file while importing the file into the HTML, and see if this works.

Comment: Just added the code of that section here.
And what do you mean with "navigate to the JS file while importing the file to HTML"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I am seeing multiple error on your JavaScript File.

For example you used `getElementById` but didn't use actual ID of the HTML element. You used the `src` of the element.

This is what you used:

```html
<input class="play-ico" type="image" src="./img/btn_play.png">
```

```js
const playIconContainer = document.getElementById('../img/btn_play.png');
```

This is what you should have used:

```html
<input class="play-ico" id="play-btn" type="image" src="./img/btn_play.png">
```

```js
const playIconContainer = document.getElementById('../img/btn_play.png');
```

Also, there are issue with comma and/or brakets in multiple places inside the code. You should fix those first.

And to answer you question:

You are importing the JS file from a cdn which itself is reading a third party library via url. This is what causing the cors issue.

I recommend keeping the JS file alongside with your HTML file and import locally, not from a cdn.

If you still want to use the cdn then there is other ways to use the cdn provided by https://lottiefiles.com/ in your html directly.